# Missing some rows when using FULL OUTER JOIN

Tags: sql-server, full-outer-join

I'm trying to join two tables with a FULL OUTER JOIN but I'm not getting what I expected because there is a a row missing.

I'm trying to join both table in 3 different columns.

Table A:

```
CallId      ASId    DateTime    CallStatus     DurationSeconds
21280070    NULL    17/07/2019  in_queue        1
21280070    2099726 17/07/2019  agent_dialing   3
21280070    2099726 17/07/2019  agent_ringing   3
21280070    2099726 17/07/2019  speaking_agent  95
21280070    NULL    17/07/2019  in_queue        1
21280070    2098692 17/07/2019  agent_dialing   1
21280070    2098692 17/07/2019  agent_ringing   6
21280070    2098692 17/07/2019  speaking_agent  10
```

Table B:

```
B.ASId  B.CallId    B.CallDetails                   B.DateTime  B.Duration
2099726 21280070    dialing                         17:21:41    3
2099726 21280070    ringing                         17:21:44    3
2099726 21280070    incoming_call_in_conversation   17:23:19    95
2098692 21280070    dialing                         17:23:21    1
2098692 21280070    ringing                         17:23:27    6
2098692 21280070    incoming_call_in_conversation   17:23:37    10
2098692 21280070    wrapup                          17:23:57    20
```

I want to get something like this:

```
A.CallId    A.ASId  A.DateTime  A.CallStatus    A.DurationSeconds       B.ASId  B.CallId    B.CallDetails   B.DateTime  B.Duration
21280070    NULL    17:21:38    in_queue        1                       NULL    NULL        NULL            NULL    NULL
21280070    2099726 17:21:41    agent_dialing   3                       2099726 21280070    dialing         17:21:41    3
21280070    2099726 17:21:44    agent_ringing   3                       2099726 21280070    ringing         17:21:44    3
21280070    2099726 17:23:19    speaking_agent  95                      2099726 21280070    incoming_call   17:23:19    95
21280070    NULL    17:23:20    in_queue        1                       NULL    NULL        NULL            NULL     NULL
21280070    2098692 17:23:21    agent_dialing   1                       2098692 21280070    dialing         17:23:21    1
21280070    2098692 17:23:27    agent_ringing   6                       2098692 21280070    ringing         17:23:27    6
21280070    2098692 17:23:37    speaking_agent  10                      2098692 21280070    incoming_call   17:23:37    10
NULL        NULL    NULL        NULL            NULL                    2098692 21280070    wrapup          17:23:57    20
```

I've tried following code:

```
SELECT *
FROM table a
FULL OUTER JOIN table b 
ON a.CallId = b.CallId AND a.ASId = b.ASId AND a.DateTime = b.DateTime
WHERE a.CallId = 21280070 
ORDER BY a.DateTime
```

And I'm getting one row less that I expected, the last one with wrapup:

```
A.CallId    A.ASId  A.DateTime  A.CallStatus    A.DurationSeconds       B.ASId  B.CallId    B.CallDetails   B.DateTime  B.Duration
21280070    NULL    17:21:38    in_queue        1                       NULL    NULL        NULL            NULL    NULL
21280070    2099726 17:21:41    agent_dialing   3                       2099726 21280070    dialing         17:21:41    3
21280070    2099726 17:21:44    agent_ringing   3                       2099726 21280070    ringing         17:21:44    3
21280070    2099726 17:23:19    speaking_agent  95                      2099726 21280070    incoming_call   17:23:19    95
21280070    NULL    17:23:20    in_queue        1                       NULL    NULL        NULL            NULL     NULL
21280070    2098692 17:23:21    agent_dialing   1                       2098692 21280070    dialing         17:23:21    1
21280070    2098692 17:23:27    agent_ringing   6                       2098692 21280070    ringing         17:23:27    6
21280070    2098692 17:23:37    speaking_agent  10                      2098692 21280070    incoming_call   17:23:37    10
```

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening? I'm not able to understand why last row is not showing.

Many thanks in advance.

Kind regards!

Comment: Learn what FULL JOIN ON returns: INNER JOIN ON rows UNION ALL unmatched left & right table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of an OUTER JOIN. A WHERE or INNER JOIN ON that requires a right/left/both table column to be not NULL after an OUTER JOIN ON removes any rows from the table(s) extended by NULLs, ie leaves only LEFT/RIGHT/INNER JOIN ON rows, ie "turns OUTER JOIN into INNER JOIN". You have that. (This is a faq.)

Answer (score 2):

Because of `a.CallId = 21280070` . Because when a `JOIN` isn't successful `a.CallId` will have a value of `NULL` and this clause won't be true.

At a guess, you probably want one of these:

```
WHERE 21280070 IN (a.CallId,b.CallId)

WHERE a.CallId = 21280070
   OR b.CallId = 21280070
```

Comment: Oh Lord! Many thanks man! You are right! What a stupid mistake I did. Really appreciated.